# how to insert keyframe to all frames?

Tags: keyframes

I insert keyframe at 1 and at 20.
[image]

[image]

I want to insert keyframes at each frames from 1 to 20

how to insert keyframe to all frames?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Select your object, go into the header menu > *Object > Animation > Bake Action*. In the pop-up panel choose *End Frame > 20* and click *OK*.

[image]

If you want to bake keyframes for a track or several tracks only, select them in the *Dope Sheet* and *Key > Bake Keyframes* or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> (not available in the *Graph Editor* but you can still use the shortcut):

[image]